# I am creating a music player in Android, but unfortunately Mediaplayer stops unexpectedly. Why?

Tags: android, service, media-queries, media-player

I am creating a music player in Android, but unfortunately Mediaplayer stops unexpectedly. If app being opened, there is no problem. But when app go to background, it stops without showing any logs.

Does anyone know what is the reason?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you use a foreground service?

Comment: how to start a forground service? starting like startService(new Intent(this, UpdaterServiceManager.class));

Comment: Dude without the code + **full logcat** not even God can help you.

Comment: How can I add code to this question? I can't find edit question option anywhere.

Comment: I have added my code as an answer. There is no log cat producing. App exits unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

```
private boolean checkError = true;
public MediaPlayer mPlayer;
private Uri mSongUri;
private Bitmap mSongBitmap;


public static PlayingFragment playingFragment;
private int songDuration;

private ArrayList<Song> mListSongs;
private int SONG_POS = 0;

private final IBinder musicBind = new PlayerBinder();

private final String ACTION_STOP = "com.emptylist.tabplayer.STOP";
private final String ACTION_NEXT = "com.emptylist.tabplayer.NEXT";
private final String ACTION_PREVIOUS = "com.emptylist.tabplayer.PREVIOUS";
private final String ACTION_PAUSE = "com.emptylist.tabplayer.PAUSE";

public static final int STATE_PAUSED = 1;
public static final int STATE_PLAYING = 2;
public int mState = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAUSE = 101;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PREVIOUS = 102;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_NEXT = 103;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_STOP = 104;
public static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 11;
private Notification.Builder notificationBuilder;
private Notification mNotification;

private SharedPreferences prefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

public class PlayerBinder extends Binder {

    public MusicService getService() {
        Log.d("test", "getService()");
        return MusicService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("test", "onBind Called ");
    return musicBind;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    initPlayer();
    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (intent != null) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(action)) {
            if (action.equals(ACTION_PAUSE)) {
                playPauseSong();
            } else if (action.equals(ACTION_NEXT)) {
                nextSong();
            } else if (action.equals(ACTION_PREVIOUS)) {
                previousSong();
            } else if (action.equals(ACTION_STOP)) {
                stopSong();
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    mPlayer.stop();
    mPlayer.release();
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

    if (checkError == false) {

        startSong(mListSongs.get(SONG_POS).getSongUri(), mListSongs.get(SONG_POS).getSongName(), mListSongs.get(SONG_POS).getmSongAlbumArt(), SONG_POS);
        checkError = true;

    } else {

        mPlayer.reset();
        try {
            if (SONG_POS != mListSongs.size() - 1) {
                SONG_POS++;
                setSongDetails(SONG_POS);

            } else {
                SONG_POS = 0;
                setSongDetails(SONG_POS);
            }
            mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), mListSongs.get(SONG_POS).getSongUri());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
        }
        mPlayer.prepareAsync();

        if (mState == STATE_PLAYING) {
            MainActivity.imgPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        } else
            MainActivity.imgPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

        editor = getSharedPreferences("MusicPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putInt("SongPosition", SONG_POS);
        editor.putString("SongURI", mListSongs.get(SONG_POS).getSongUri().toString());
        editor.commit();

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

    Log.d("EEE", String.valueOf(what) + "," + String.valueOf(extra));
    checkError = false;
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
    new ProgressUpdater();
}

private void initPlayer() {
    mPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        try {
            Class<?> cMediaTimeProvider = Class.forName("android.media.MediaTimeProvider");
            Class<?> cSubtitleController = Class.forName("android.media.SubtitleController");
            Class<?> iSubtitleControllerAnchor = Class.forName("android.media.SubtitleController$Anchor");
            Class<?> iSubtitleControllerListener = Class.forName("android.media.SubtitleController$Listener");

            Constructor constructor = cSubtitleController.getConstructor(new Class[]{Context.class, cMediaTimeProvider, iSubtitleControllerListener});

            Object subtitleInstance = constructor.newInstance(getApplicationContext(), null, null);

            Field f = cSubtitleController.getDeclaredField("mHandler");

            f.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                f.set(subtitleInstance, new Handler());
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            } finally {
                f.setAccessible(false);
            }

            Method setsubtitleanchor = mPlayer.getClass().getMethod("setSubtitleAnchor", cSubtitleController, iSubtitleControllerAnchor);

            setsubtitleanchor.invoke(mPlayer, subtitleInstance, null);
            //Log.e("", "subtitle is setted :p");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}

public void startSong(Uri songuri, String songName, Bitmap bitmap, int position) {

    //Set data & start playing music
    setSongDetails(position);
    mPlayer.reset();
    mState = STATE_PLAYING;
    mSongUri = songuri;
    mSongBitmap = bitmap;

    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), mSongUri);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
    }
    mPlayer.prepareAsync();
    if (mState == STATE_PLAYING) {
        MainActivity.imgPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
    } else {
        MainActivity.imgPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    }
    Log.d("EEESonfPOs", String.valueOf(position));
    editor = getSharedPreferences("MusicPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putInt("SongPosition", SONG_POS);
    editor.putString("SongURI", mListSongs.get(SONG_POS).getSongUri().toString());
    editor.commit();
    updateNotification(songName);

}

public void playPauseSong() {

    if (mState == STATE_PAUSED) {
        mState = STATE_PLAYING;
        mPlayer.start();
        MainActivity.imgPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
    } else {
        mState = STATE_PAUSED;
        mPlayer.pause();
        MainActivity.imgPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

    }
}

public boolean isPlayingg() {
    return mPlayer.isPlaying();
}

public int getPosn() {
    return mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

public int getDur() {
    int n = songDuration;
    return songDuration;
}

public void pausePlayer() {
    mPlayer.pause();
}


private void setSongDetails(int position) {

    MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    byte[] rawArt;
    Bitmap art = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    mmr.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), mListSongs.get(position).getSongUri());
    rawArt = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();

    // if rawArt is null then no cover art is embedded in the file or is not
    // recognized as such.
    if (null != rawArt) {
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawArt, 0, rawArt.length, bfo),
                100, 100,
                true);
        MainActivity.imgSongArt.setImageBitmap(bm);
        MainActivity.tvSongName.setText(mListSongs.get(position).getSongName());
        MainActivity.tvSongArtist.setText(mListSongs.get(position).getmSongArtist());
    } else {
        MainActivity.imgSongArt.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_album_art);
        MainActivity.tvSongName.setText(mListSongs.get(position).getSongName());
        MainActivity.tvSongArtist.setText(mListSongs.get(position).getmSongArtist());
    }

}

public void stopSong() {
    mPlayer.stop();
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    //System.exit(0);
}

public void nextSong() {

    if (SONG_POS != mListSongs.size() - 1) {
        startSong(mListSongs.get(SONG_POS + 1).getSongUri(), mListSongs.get(SONG_POS + 1).getSongName(), mListSongs.get(SONG_POS + 1).getmSongAlbumArt(), SONG_POS + 1);
        SONG_POS++;
    } else {
        SONG_POS = 0;
        startSong(mListSongs.get(0).getSongUri(), mListSongs.get(0).getSongName(), mListSongs.get(0).getmSongAlbumArt(), 0);

    }

    editor = getSharedPreferences("MusicPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putInt("SongPosition", SONG_POS);
    editor.putString("SongURI", mListSongs.get(SONG_POS).getSongUri().toString());
    editor.commit();
}

public void previousSong() {

    if (SONG_POS != 0) {
        startSong(mListSongs.get(SONG_POS - 1).getSongUri(), mListSongs.get(SONG_POS - 1).getSongName(), mListSongs.get(SONG_POS - 1).getmSongAlbumArt(), SONG_POS - 1);
        SONG_POS--;
    } else {
        startSong(mListSongs.get(mListSongs.size() - 1).getSongUri(), mListSongs.get(mListSongs.size() - 1).getSongName(), mListSongs.get(mListSongs.size() - 1).getmSongAlbumArt(), mListSongs.size() - 1);
        SONG_POS = mListSongs.size() - 1;
    }

    editor = getSharedPreferences("MusicPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putInt("SongPosition", SONG_POS);
    editor.putString("SongURI", mListSongs.get(SONG_POS).getSongUri().toString());
    editor.commit();

}

public void setSongURI(Uri uri) {
    this.mSongUri = uri;
}

public void setmSongBitmap(Bitmap mSongBitmap) {
    this.mSongBitmap = mSongBitmap;
}


public void setSelectedSong(int pos, int notification_id) {
    SONG_POS = pos;
    NOTIFICATION_ID = notification_id;
    setSongURI(mListSongs.get(SONG_POS).getSongUri());
    setmSongBitmap(mListSongs.get(SONG_POS).getmSongAlbumArt());
    showNotification();
    startSong(mListSongs.get(SONG_POS).getSongUri(), mListSongs.get(SONG_POS).getSongName(), mListSongs.get(SONG_POS).getmSongAlbumArt(), SONG_POS);
}

public void setSongList(ArrayList<Song> listSong) {
    mListSongs = listSong;
}

public void showNotification() {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    Intent intent;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_mediacontroller);

    notificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.notify_song_name, mListSongs.get(SONG_POS).getSongName());

    intent = new Intent(ACTION_STOP);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE_STOP, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notify_btn_stop, pendingIntent);

    intent = new Intent(ACTION_PAUSE);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE_PAUSE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notify_btn_pause, pendingIntent);

    intent = new Intent(ACTION_PREVIOUS);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE_PREVIOUS, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notify_btn_previous, pendingIntent);

    intent = new Intent(ACTION_NEXT);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE_NEXT, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notify_btn_next, pendingIntent);

    mNotification = notificationBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setOngoing(true)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContent(notificationView)
            .setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR)
            .build();
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
}

private void updateNotification(String songName) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notify_song_name, songName);
    mNotification.contentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.img_notification, mListSongs.get(SONG_POS).getmSongAlbumArt());
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to release media player reference in the onPause method. Try it out. It may work!